# preg_replace match and replace exact count of characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

How can I add a count or whatever else to this `preg_replace` so it replaces only when it encounters 2 or 3 `>` and not anything more or less than that?

**Original**

```
$str = '>>This is code>> This is text >>>This is a link>>>. >>>>This need not be replaced>>>>';

$patterns = array('#>>((?!>[^>]).+?)>>#','#>>>((?!>[^>]).+?)>>>#');
$actions = array('[code]$1[/code]','[a]$1[/a]');

echo preg_replace($patterns, $actions, $str );

//output
[code]This is code[/code] This is text >[code]This is a link[/code]>. [code]>>This need not be replaced[/code]>>
```

**Expected**

```
[code]This is code[/code] This is text [a]This is a link[/a]. >>>>This need not be replaced>>>>
```

What I'm trying to do here is, only match `>>` and `>>>` and not anything else, like the third one in the string. What I current end up doing is matching everyone in there.

I tried adding a `{2}` and `{3}` to `$patterns` like so :

`$patterns = array('#>>{2}((?!>[^>]).+?)>>{2}#','#>>>{3}((?!>[^>]).+?)>>>{3}#');`,

but that just wrecks things up further.

I plan on adding more patterns there later, so how can I tell the regex to only look for 2 or 3 `>` (or more later) and not just all `>` in the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$str = '>>This i>s code>> This is text
>>>This is >> a li>nk>>>.
>>>>This need not be replaced>>>>
>>Bad > stuff>>>
';

$patterns = array(
    '#(?<!>)(>{2})(?!>)(.*?)(?<!>)\1(?!>)#',
    '#(?<!>)(>{3})(?!>)(.*?)(?<!>)\1(?!>)#',
    );
$actions = array('[code]$2[/code]','[a]$2[/a]');

echo preg_replace($patterns, $actions, $str );
```

Comment: Except that if there's a `>` inside the sentence it wont work.

Comment: Works, but now bad stuff too gets replaced

Comment: Ok. Thanks for helping. I'll improve on this. Still have a long way to go.

Comment: You can simplify the pattern a little by reversing the arrays.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$str = '>>This is code>> This is text >>>This is a link>>>. >>>>This need not be replaced>>>>';

$patterns = array('#>>>>(.+?)>>>>#', '#>>>([^>].+?)>>>#', '#>>([^>].+?)>>#');
$actions = array('$1', '[a]$1[/a]', '[code]$1[/code]');
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
[code]This is code[/code] This is text [a]This is a link[/a]. This need not be replaced
```